# i have successfully gotten an image fader to work with just <img> tags, but cant get it to work with <a> tags

Tags: jquery, html

this is the first post from an extreme noob in jquery, seeking any help at all, no matter how miniscule.

I have 3 pictures I am trying to fade which works well (learnt from youtube) with  tags but when i put links and embed them in a div like below, i become totally lost, especially with .next, and .parent() syntax used in the jquery below.

HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div id="slider">       
<a href ="#"><img Class="is-showing" src="includes/templates/Custom/images/navbox2.gif"/> </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href = "#"> <img  src="includes/templates/Custom/images/image1.gif" width = "100%" /> </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href = "#"> <img  src="includes/templates/Custom/images/navbox.gif" /> </a>
</div>

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
function slideShow() {

  var showing = $('#slider .is-showing');
  var count = showing.parent().parent();

 var next = count.next().length ? showing.parent().parent().next().children(':second') : closest('#Slider').children(':second');


  showing.fadeOut(800, function() { next.fadeIn(800).addClass('is-showing'); }).removeClass('is-showing');

  setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
}
```

MORE QUESTIONS
does this line of code "`var count = showing.parent().parent();`" point to the div #slider like I think it should, or is that invalid?

"`showing.parent().parent().next().children(':second')`", I fear this snippet of code might be too long to even make sense (does to me though, but what do noobs know).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntactical errors in the code you have written..

```
does this line of code "var count = showing.parent().parent();" 
point to the div #slider
```

Yes it points to the slider div.

Better  .. `showing.closest('div');`

I don't think this makes any sense

```
showing.parent().parent().next().children(':second');
```

This gets the ***second child*** in the `next div` **which is not present** according to the HTML above..

Also `closest('#Slider').children(':second');` does not make any sense..

**FULL CODE** .. After some assumptions

```
function slideShow() {

    var showing = $('#slider .is-showing');
    var count = showing.closest('div');

    var next = count.next('div').length 
                ? showing.closest('div').next('div').children(':first') 
                :  count.find('img');


    showing.fadeOut(800, function() {
        next.fadeIn(800).addClass('is-showing');
    }).removeClass('is-showing');

    setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
}​
```

**UPDATE**

> you said the next div is not present,

I mean to say `.children(':second');`  does not make any sense(not next on the div )  as each div has only one child , the anchor element . .children() will get the immediate children and not the nested ones..

> first image a class "is-showing", he then used the .next() to get to
>   the next img element

This will not work for the HTML above as next will get the immediate sibling , and when you do .next() on the image you get nothing as there no siblings for the image.

> why are we adding and removing the class (is-showing) within the fade
>   function

Because fade function is asynchronous.. So you need to do that in callback . Otherwise it will be reflected immediately.

Comment: is correct, why are we adding and removing the class (is-showing) within the fade function. I know it is keeping track of position, but why do we need to do this if the .next() call will point to the next image already, and upon reaching the last image in the div, we exit the if function and return to the first image in the div.  Phew! Finally, in your code you referenced the first child within the next div in your true condition for the if statement. wouldn't that point to the <a> tag and not the <img> tag. Thats it, i promise i have no more questions, these answers would allow me to proceed.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I totally understand that there are no sibling img tags in my html, i was still refering to the tutorial i watched seeting up for my second question above. i would like to know why he added the "addclass" and "removeclass". you have solved like half of my problems with your answer about first child, i honestly thought the <a> tag was the first, and img second, thanks alot. but the unanswered question is still why is he adding and removing classes when he is using .next() like we both agree to go to the next siblin img (still refering to his tutorial). I just don't

Comment: what "addclass" and "removeclass" where doing in "HIS" code (I have being studying his original using just img within a div, so imgs are all siblings, and I seem to be making progress understanding everything else, so i can customize it for my needs)

Comment: .removeClass('is-showing'); runs first as fadeOut is asynchronous ... So he is removing that class to the current and adding the class to the new element ( this runs later ) in the callback function..

Comment: you are right where in <a> is the first tag .. As the image is inside the <a> , the image becomes the first child of <a> , but it is not the direct child of <div> ( So .children(':second') ) does not make any sense as .children() gets only the immediate children , not the nested ones

Comment: Gosh, I can't vote you up, I need like 15 votes. Thanks a alot, all questions answered. I really really appreciate the answers.

Comment: @Charles .. no problem at all .. You are welcome :) .. It should be easy once you get a grasp of it.. Util then it just takes some time ;)

Comment: hey Sushanth, I do not know if you are still there, but please this is related to your add/remove class post. Please that question has broken into one more question. From your teaching so far i can understand he is adding and removing the Class "is-showing", and the showing.fade function is executed before the callback "next.fade" function is executed. but i am still wondering "WHY", not "HOW", is he keeping track of the class "is-showing", i don't see the use for this. var showing is already pointing to the first pic, then var next points to the next and next and so forth. so with just var

Comment: var showing and var next, we have successfully pointed to all the pictures. Please what am i missing? this is the only jquery code that will go on my webpage and its kicking by butt. Please so we are on the same page, i only see the point of the class "is-showing" to be able to point to the first pic as we did in var showing, after that please what is the point of keeping track of the by removing "is-showing" from previous pic and adding to current pic, when we can just simply move to the next sibling img tag with the "showing.next()" command. (please still refering to his tutorial, thanks

Comment: Here is-active can be used to keep a tab of what image is exactly being shown .. It will make more sense of adding/removing the class if the active image is shown differently in the UI , maybe a border or a special effect to the current active image . Other than that I don't see any use for the class being added

Comment: hey Sushanth, thanks for all your help. finally got it working, i actually see why he is using the addclass and removeclass after hours of debugging his code. I thought the fade () command with the embeded callback function would execute all the images at once, but that was not the case. I guess i was having a problem with the jquery code flow, like the "timeout" command function. once i figured out what the timeout was doing, and i used your tip for first child not second (lol) voila! image slider with links, wohooooo! thanks again for your guidiance sensei.